# Use Kubectl access *existing* GCP cluster

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, kubectl

I've been able to deploy things via helm, and even directly with a docker push to a GCP container. But I can't figure out how to get `kubectl` to access the GCP cluster. When I search for accessing a GCP cluster via `kubectl`, it always talks about creating a new cluster. I already have one. I'm still learning this; so in the process I was able to get this to work with a Service rather than a User. However, I'd like to force my `kubectl` (especially) to use my GCP's admin user. This is a personal, throwaway account; I wouldn't take this approach on a more serious environment.

How can I tell `kubectl`, hey, sign in as `joe@example.com`? For that matter, how do I display whatever credentials (user, service, etc) it is trying to use to authenticate?

Answer (score 0):

Check if `gcloud auth list` outputs the correct account.

Did you authenticate against your GKE cluster?

Check if `kubectl config get-contexts` outputs correct cluster contexts.

You can auth against your cluster by running `gcloud container clusters get-credentials <cluster name> --region <cluster region> --project <gcp project of cluster>`

Answer (score 0):

To store cluster information for kubectl, first you need to review the current context configured for `kubectl`. Kubernetes uses a config YAML file to store cluster authentication, this file stores a group of access parameters called contexts; to review the content of this file you can use this command:

```
kubectl config view
```

Then, we need to check the `kubeconfig file` generated for your [cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-access-for-kubectl#store_info).
If you have not generated a `kubeconfig` context for your cluster, you can run this command:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials CLUSTER_NAME
```

Once the kubeconfig has been generated, you can run individual `kubectl` commands against your cluster, so you can use this command to add the user and password to your configuration file:

```
kubectl config --kubeconfig=config-demo set-credentials experimenter --username=exp --password=some-password
```

Note: `config-demo` must be replaced with the name of your config file.

You can check this public [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/#define-clusters-users-and-contexts) if you need more assistance with access to `kubectl` in Kubernetes.